# Respecting unique_constraint without updating primary key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a table in mysql, let's say:
`ID - year - month`

I have placed a unique_constraint on `year` and `month`. This way a year can't have two the same months.

`ID` is used to retrieve the combination of a year and a month. Let's say we have the following values:

```
ID -  year  -  month
1  -  20    -  1
2  -  20    -  2
3  -  20    -  5
```

Then `ID` 3 would be May of 2020. This table however, is built dynamically. I upload specific data and need to insert all the combination of years and months.

First I used the MySQL commando `REPLACE INTO` because I thought it won't add a non-unique row. And it doesn't add a non-unique row, but it updates the `ID` each time resulting in my foreign keys getting messed up.

How do I fix this? Just using `INSERT`? Because of the unique_constraint the insert will just fail and return an error.

Now I have fixed it like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DTBS);
         $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID FROM periods WHERE month=? AND year=?");
         $stmt->bind_param("ii", $month_, $year_);
         $month_ = $month;
         $year_ = $year;
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->bind_result($id);
         $stmt->fetch();
         $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
         $stmt->close();


         if ($rows == 0) {
             $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO periods (year, month) VALUES (?, ?)");
             $stmt->bind_param("ii", $year_, $month_);
             $year_ = $year;
             $month_ = $month;
             $stmt->execute();
             $stmt->close();
         }
          $conn->close();
```

Comment: `$stmt->num_rows` will not work here. Fetch the result first

Comment: @Dharman I am doing a fetch, with `$stmt->fetch()`?

Comment: I meant you need to call `get_result()` or `store_result()`

Comment: @Dharman Oh yes, you're right! Thanks.

Comment: If you are only starting with PHP then I recommend learning PDO instead of mysqli. It is much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`:

```
insert into periods(year, month)
values (?, ?)
on duplicate key update year = values(year)
```

This takes advantage of the unique constraint on `(year, month)`. When a duplicate tuple is met, MySQL does not `insert` it, and goes to the `on duplicate key` clause, where a dummy update` is performed.

Comment: Works like a charm! I've looked a lot into this problem but only stumbled on `REPLACE INTO` or very complex SQL syntaxes with if-statements etc. Best and most simple solution! Will accept soon.